# Is there an isomorphism between Euler angles and Quaternions?

Tags: category-theory, quaternions

Non math expert question here.

To keep things more defined let's restrict the Euler angles to Yaw Pitch Roll in that order with all angles between 0 and 2pi.

So there are two YPR's according to the definition above that map to a rotational orientation as well as two unit Quaternions that do the same. For quaternions the unit negative quaternion shares an equivalent rotational orientation with it's positive partner when mapped to 3D space. For euler angles there are two paths that can be taken within 0-2pi that can produce the same rotational orientation, one path is short and straightforward the other path involves rotating 180 degrees across the yaw and flipping back past 90 degrees to achieve the same orientation. Thus when mapping quaternions to euler angles you get two sets with each element of the set mapping to two other elements in the opposing set.

A friend of mine says that there is a technique you can do which is called "isomorphism." (never heard of a technique referred to as an isomorphism would also like to confirm if this is used by mathematicians) Which is to arbitrarily choose that the negative quaternion is mapped to the longer YPR and the positive quaternion is mapped to the shorter YPR and to ignore the other mappings and you can therefore say there is an "isomorphism" between quaternions and euler angles.

I agree that you can choose to ignore certain mappings and create arbitrary mappings such that an isomorphism exists between quaternions and euler angles but is this really how the terminology is used? Do people call this technique an isomorphism or is my friend getting a bit creative here? If I were to approach an expert mathematician and ask him without prior context other then the definition of YPR above if an isomorphism between quaternions and euler angles exist what would he say?

My intuition is telling me if you mess with the mappings between quaternions and euler angles you sort of get something different that's no longer quite a quaternion. It seems to me that is becomes sort of a special quaternion that holds an arbitrary definition that says the negative quaternion maps to a specific YPR. Is my intuition correct or is my friend right?

Comment: Does [the Wiki page on the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles) address your concern?

Comment: @Kajelad no did you read what I wrote? I am aware of the math between conversions. This is a category theory question. Does an isomorphism exist between quaternions and euler angles given that there are two representations of YPR for each quaternion and two representations of Quaternions for each YPR.

Comment: When you say "negative quaternion", are you referring to $-q$? I don't get your question since $q$ and $-q$ represent the same rotation i.e., they are not "different paths", they are the same (short) path.

Comment: @MauricioCeleLopezBelon There are 3 entities here. Rotational orientations, Quaternions and Euler Angles. As you said two Quaternions represent a single rotational orientation. But two Euler Angles within 360 degrees ALSO represent a single rotational orientation. By paths I mean Euler Angles (or paths taken to achieve a rotational orientation). So every element in the set of all Rotational Orientations maps to two euler angles and two unit quaternions. What my friend did was create an arbitrary mapping from Quaternions to Euler Anlges such that the mapping is one to one.

Comment: @MauricioCeleLopezBelon This is done by forming an arbitrary mapping from the negative quat to a longer YPR and the positive quat to the shorter YPR of the same rotational orientation such that every quat value maps to a single YPR and vice versa. My friends claim is that this proves Quats and Euler Angles are isomorphic because such a arbitrary mapping forms a bijection. My claim is that by creating an arbitrary mapping you are creating a new entity. Something similar to a quat but not quite and that he proved isomorphism on this new thing but not on Quats and euler angles in general.

Comment: Ok so rotation, a as mapping of one vector to other, is not unique in the sense that you can define different rotation "paths" from one vector to the other. For a single quaternion $q$, that path is unique no matter the sign, so $-q$ and $q$ refer to the same path. That quaternion $q$ can be converted to Euler angles YPR in such a way that the Euler angles produces the *same* rotation path than $q$ (or $-q$). Since YPR is not-unique then the map from quaternions to YPR would be an injective map (not bijection).

Comment: Well, there are infinitely many quaternions representing the same "path" since any quaternion with same rotation angle plus $4\pi$ will represent the same "path". However if we restrict ourselves to angles from $0$ to $4\pi$ then a single "path" (in a single direction) would correspond to a single quaternion. With "direction" I mean the sense of rotation, because the same path can be traveled in opposite direction and that correspond to the inverse quaternion $q^{-1}$

Comment: @MauricioCeleLopezBelon Yes there are infinitely many paths from one vector to another. But as I stated in the problem the path is restricted to Yaw Pitch Roll (YPR) in that order with all values limited between 0 and 2pi. This effectively limits the paths to 2 total for YPR: A longer path and a shorter path. What my friend did is map positive quats to the shorter path and negative quats to the longer path and he says this proves an isomorphism between quat and YPR. My claim is that this is false. The mapping is arbitrary it only proves isomorpism against a new type of quaternion he created.

Comment: The arbitrary mapping that my friend defines DOES form a bijection and an isomorphism. However I'm saying that it only forms an isomorphism on this new entity he created. It does not PROVE that an isomorphism exists on Quaternions and YPR because his mapping created something entirely different. Do you see what I'm saying here? Like you said Quaternions to YPR and YPR to Quaternions is an injective relationship indicating no isomorphism. My question is who is correct? Is there an isomorphism?

Comment: As an example for YPR in degrees (20, 20, 0) = (200, 160, 180) One path is shorter another path is longer. Both paths end up at the same exact rotational orientation. @MauricioCeleLopezBelon

Comment: Since a particular path+direction corresponds to a single quaternion (restricting angle to [$0$ $2\pi$]) and that quaternion can be mapped to a YPR producing the *same* path as the quaternion and in YPR can be only 2 paths (short and long) then the corresponding YPR for the path of quaternion is one of the posibilities so is unique. So it seem to be possible to create a bijection from quaternions to YPR. Having said that, it would be wrong to associate negative quaternions to the other possible YPR since it doesn't correspond to quaternion path.

Comment: @MauricioCeleLopezBelon What do you mean by "doesn't correspond to quaternion path?" Also what do you mean that a single quaternion maps to a YPR? all Quaternions map to two possible YPRs. One quaternion value maps to two YPRs while one YPR maps to Two Quaternions. Maybe I'm not understanding what you're saying?

Comment: I am talking about **paths** not orientations. If we restrict quaternions to be unit length (to avoid difference on wight) with angles in [$0$ $2\pi$] and "twist-free" (in the sense of "swing-twist decomposition") then there is a unique quaternion producing each path+direction rotation. I am not talking about just final orientation, I am talking about the path to reach that orientation and the sense of rotation (direction). You can visualize it as a unique axis of rotation + (signed) angle.

Comment: On YPR side, having similar restrictions on the angles, you mentioned there are two possible paths to reach the *same* orientation. So it should be possible to identify a quaternion (path + direction) with a YPR (path + direction) in a bijection. Again, I am not saying that there is a unique quaternion producing a given orientation. I am saying that, given suitable restrictions, there's a unique quat producing a path+direction to reach that orientation. That can be used to construct a bijection assuming the YPR representation can be restricted to have unique YPR per each path+direction.

Comment: I don't think there can be an isomorphism between YPR (modulo whatever makes it two-to-one) and quaternions (modulo the need to equate $q$ and $-q$ as they yield the same rotation. The reason: in YPR world you can run into a gimbal lock, but in the quaternion world you won't. This is a topological difference. YPR domain looks like the cartesian product of three circles. The unit quaternions form the 3-dimensional surface of a sphere in 4-dimensional space. These two are not homeomorphic. That, in itself would not rule out an isomorphism, but it does rule out a continuous isomorphism.

Comment: However, it is not entirely clear to me what kind of an answer you are looking for. I brought up  gimbal locks, because it is something that YPR people are often familiar with.